# How to fix undefined offset in laravel view?

Tags: laravel

I want to show the only the products that match the item list products. I'm using the controller to pass all products data and the item list but i get error when matching the data within my for-each loop.

```
<tbody>
    @php 
        $x=0; 
    @endphp 
    @foreach ($orders as $order)
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>{{$order->order_date}}</td>
        <td>{{$order->client_name}}</td>
        <td>{{$order->client_contact}}</td>
        <td class="details-control">
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-xs" onclick="test()">
                <b>Items : </b> {{$item_count["$x"]}}
            </button>
                <!-- Split button -->
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn btn-info btn-xs"><b>Items : </b> {{$item_count["$x"]}}</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn btn-info btn-xs" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#extra_info{{$x}}" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div id="extra_info{{$x}}" class="collapse">
                    @for ($y = 0; $y < $item_count[ "$x"]; $y++) 
                        @foreach ($products_data as $product) @if($item_list[ "$y"]->product_id==$product['product_id'])
                        <li> {{$product['product_name']}} </li>
                        @endif 
                        @endforeach 
                    @endfor
                </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @php $x++; @endphp @endforeach
</tbody>
```

This is my controller.

```
public function index()
    {
        $orders=Order::all();
        $products_data=Product::all()->toArray();
        foreach ($orders as $order) {
            $item_count[] = DB::table('order_item')->whereorder_id($order->order_id)->count();
            $item_list=DB::table('order_item')->whereorder_id($order->order_id)->get()->toArray();
        }

        return view('manageorders',compact('orders','item_count','products_data','item_list'));
    }
```

Comment: Check my answer @Pemba Tshiring

Answer (score 0):

Actually variable index should not be wrapped in quotes, only strings should be in quotes. So remove quotes from all the variables where you're setting as index of array

Your new code should be:

```
<tbody>
    @php 
        $x=0; 
    @endphp 
    @foreach ($orders as $order)
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>{{$order->order_date}}</td>
        <td>{{$order->client_name}}</td>
        <td>{{$order->client_contact}}</td>
        <td class="details-control">
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-xs" onclick="test()">
                <b>Items : </b> {{$item_count[$x]}}
            </button>
                <!-- Split button -->
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn btn-info btn-xs"><b>Items : </b> {{$item_count[$x]}}</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn btn-info btn-xs" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#extra_info{{$x}}" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div id="extra_info{{$x}}" class="collapse">
                    @for ($y = 0; $y < $item_count[$x]; $y++) 
                        @foreach ($products_data as $product) @if($item_list[$y]->product_id==$product['product_id'])
                        <li> {{$product['product_name']}} </li>
                        @endif 
                        @endforeach 
                    @endfor
                </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @php 
        $x++; 
    @endphp 
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```